# "tree.. Room opening upon it." - meaning?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

I would like to understand the following sentence, as the meaning of "opening upon" is not clear to me:

> There was a compound adjoining, filled with rank reed and a solitary
> pipal tree. Nicholson said that the ghost generally appeared in one of
> the rooms **opening upon** it, and this I selected as the one in which to
> spend the night.

Comment: The rooms open upon (or to) the compound.

Comment: @StephenS Thanks, but this "open upon" phrase is not clear to me :) Also I guess that is how you know the author means the compound and not the tree?

Comment: We can say a room “opens to” some area, meaning it has a doorway to that area. For instance, my kitchen opens to my back yard, or my bathroom opens to the hallway. “opens upon” is the same idea.

Comment: @StephenS Ah, right, so like facing, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I have reduced the sentence to focus on the parts which are most useful to decipher the answer to your question:

> There was a **compound** adjoining....Nicholson said that the ghost generally appeared in one of the rooms opening upon **it**

The word "it" refers to the compound.  So the room is opening upon the compound.

Now what does "**opening upon**" mean?

This means that the room is accessible from the compound and vice versa.  Specifically, there is a door or other opening which can be used to come and go that faces the compound.